# Node.js and express - how to read a cookie but is undefined

Tags: node.js, express

I use the below to set a cookie using express.

```
res.cookie('test', 'yes', { 
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 365*2*24*60*60*1000), 
    httpOnly: true 
});
```

I am using the middleware to try and read the cookie:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());

var cookie_id = req.cookies.test;
```

Problem is that cookie_id is undefined whne it would be 'yes'

```
Express server listening on port 8060 in development mode
TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbServers/rtbNodejsServer/nodeServer/app.js:48:29
    at callbacks (/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbServers/rtbNodejsServer/nodeServer/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:272:11)
    at param (/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbServers/rtbNodejsServer/nodeServer/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:246:11)
    at pass (/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbServers/rtbNodejsServer/nodeServer/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:253:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbServers/rtbNodejsServer/nodeServer/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:4)
    at Object.handle (/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbServers/rtbNodejsServer/nodeServer/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:45:10)
    at next (/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbServers/rtbNodejsServer/nodeServer/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/http.js:204:15)
    at Object.methodOverride [as handle] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbServers/rtbNodejsServer/nodeServer/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/methodOverride.js:35:5)
    at next (/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbServers/rtbNodejsServer/nodeServer/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/http.js:204:15)
    at Object.bodyParser [as handle] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbServers/rtbNodejsServer/nodeServer/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:88:61)
```

What did I do wrong?

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  test=yes
Host    127.0.0.1:8060
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
```

```
// Configuration
app.configure(function() {
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
});
```

Comment: Can you use fiddler / firebug or google chrome, and see if the cookie is being passed to the route (where you are checking for the cookie). (Chekc the HTTP headers of the HTTP request). Update - the cookie is being set correctly, and being passed. So it is only that the middle ware may not be in the correct manner..... Can you check if the app.use(express.cookieParser()); is before the line which defines the app.get (where you are checking fo the cookie) ? Are you defining the app.use(cookieparser) inside the get route definition?

Comment: Hi, I added the firebug headers.

Comment: Hi...I added the code where I add the cookie parser.  in the app.configure section

Answer (score 35):

You need to use `express.cookieParser()` **before** `app.router`; middleware is run *in order*, meaning it's never even reaching `cookieParser()` before your route is executed.

Try this:

```
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Comment: Be careful that `cookieParser` isn't now bundled to express and you need to install it separately using `npm install cookie-parser --save-dev`

Answer (score 13):

Most middleware (like cookieParser) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately.

**Install cookie-parser**:

```
npm install cookie-parser
```

**Usage**

```
var express      = require('express')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

var app = express()
app.use(cookieParser())
```

https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding `app.use(express.cookieParser());` above the `app.router`.

Comment: Be careful that `cookieParser` isn't now bundled to express and you need to install it separately using `npm install cookie-parser --save-dev`

Comment: @FarzadYZ Why the `--save-dev`? Isn't `--save` enough?

Comment: @BlueEyesWhiteDragon You're right. It has to be installed by `--save` because it's mandatory on production.