# Pass userinfo to NodeJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have a Angular form that passed the values to NodeJS. I am able to post the values present in the form. I also want to send the logged in user information to NodeJS.

My form:

```
<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="title" ng-model="post.title">
<input type="text" placeholder="category" ng-model="post.category">
<input type="submit" ng-click="newpost(post)">Post
</form>
```

Angular:

```
var user = $cookies.get('user');
$scope.post = function(post){
    $http.post('/newpost', post).then ...
}
```

How do I pass the user information along with the `post` to NodeJS?

Thanks.

Comment: Usually, logged in user data is accessible through `req.session.user` in the backend. Try logging `req.session` and pick the correct field you require.

Comment: The browser cookie should be send with the request automatically. Did you already try to read the cookie as described in this answer to [Node.js and express - how to read a cookie](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34566157/1960455)? But in general you should relay on the user information (if you want to grant/deny certain access to resources) that is stored in the server side session, and not on a cookie that could be changed on the client side.

Comment: @t.niese thanks mate. I am able to read the cookie value in Node now. Thanks a ton. Trying to put that along with the post data in Mongodb now.

Comment: But as I said, take care about if you want to trust this information. Cookies can be changed by the client, so the `user` cookie could contain any value and might be something that you do not expect. If you want use this information to save with a post where you want to be sure that this was really the user posting, then you should not use the cookies. A client could then create posts under any username.

Comment: Oh. That's alarming. How do I trust a cookie than? What's the best way to go about this? You're right. I want to use the cookie to find the userid and post that in the post.

Answer (score 0):

to post the user info along with **post** object you can add **user** keys in post object.

example:

```
var user = $cookies.get('user');

 $scope.post = function(post){

    post.username = user.username;
    post.email = user.email

    $http.post('/newpost', post)
    .then(){}
    .catch(){}
 }
```